# exactRLRT()` function in `RLRsim` fails to recognise `lmerMod` object

Tags: r, lme4

I am having trouble getting the `exactRLRT()` function in the `RLRsim` package to work.

```
library(faraway)
library(RLRsim)
data(eggs)
cmods <- lmer(Fat ~ 1 + (1|Lab:Technician:Sample), data=eggs)
exactRLRT(cmods)
```

This generates the error

```
Error in exactRLRT(cmods) : Invalid <m> specified.
```

In the help for `RLRsim::exactRLRT` it says

```
The fitted model under the alternative or, for testing in models with multiple variance components, the reduced model containing only the random effect to be tested (see Details), an lme, lmerMod or spm object
```

But `cmods` *was* an `lmerMod` object, so why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works for me, I post it here so you can check and we can see what is causing your error:

```
library(faraway)
library(RLRsim)
library(lme4)
data(eggs)
cmods <- lmer(Fat ~ 1 + (1|Lab:Technician:Sample), data=eggs)
exactRLRT(cmods)


    simulated finite sample distribution of RLRT.

    (p-value based on 10000 simulated values)

data:  
RLRT = 14.382, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

My sessionInfo() :

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lme4_1.1-21   Matrix_1.2-17 RLRsim_3.1-3  faraway_1.0.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] minqa_1.2.4     MASS_7.3-51.4   compiler_3.6.1  tools_3.6.1    
 [5] mgcv_1.8-28     Rcpp_1.0.2      splines_3.6.1   nlme_3.1-140   
 [9] grid_3.6.1      nloptr_1.2.1    boot_1.3-23     lattice_0.20-38
```